# unable to understand basic merge sort algorithm

Tags: recursion, mergesort

I am trying to learn the merge sort alogrithm but I am running in to a block in my understanding.

Follwoing is the starting piece of the merge sort alogrithm:

```
def mergeSort(nlist):
    print("Splitting ",nlist)
    if len(nlist)>1:
        mid = len(nlist)//2
        lefthalf = nlist[:mid]
        righthalf = nlist[mid:]

        mergeSort(lefthalf)
        mergeSort(righthalf)
```

The function mergesort is being called over and over agin and this will change the value of the left half and right half so that when the second mergesort function is called it will have ony a single element. where does the rest of the list get saved and how does it get retrieved again ? . I am not able to understand the flow of the program.

How do I understand this I am not able to earp my head around how this works...

Comment: The code is missing a merge function.

Comment: Hi, i did not add the full code here just the part until which i can understand

Comment: All the code in the question does is recursively split the array in half until the length == 1. Once two instances of length == 1 occur, then those will be merged to form a sorted run of 2 elements. No merging takes place until the first two instances of length == 1 occur. After that, the code will follow the stack up and down as it alternates between dividing the array and merging the parts.